# My python script that scans IP addresses and sends commands to each using Telnet does not work I keep getting "Error occurred"

Tags: python, networking, telnet

I have python script witch scans IP addresses and sends commands to each using Telnet, but it does not work, I don't know why, I'm just getting `Error occurred`

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
 
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
 
 
def h4ck_th3_w0rld(HOST):
    user = 'admin'
    password = 'admin'
    tn = None
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 23, 5)
 
        tn.read_until("Username: ", 5)
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password: ", 5)
            tn.write(password + "\n")
 
        tn.write("ls\n")
        tn.write("sendcmd\n")
        tn.write("exit\n")
 
        print(tn.read_all())
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Error occurred'
    finally:
        if tn:
            tn.close()
 
 
for i in range(1, 256):
    for j in range(0, 21):
        ip_address = '192.168.%d.%d' % (j, i)
        h4ck_th3_w0rld(ip_address)
```

Comment: If you don't catch exceptions (or properly print the exception you get) you might get a better error message, telling you more precisely what's wrong.

Comment: If the port 23 is not open for an address, you'll get a time out error. Since you are not printing the exception you only see your message.

Comment: ok so I googled  it and placed traceback.print_exc() instead `Error occurred` and Im getting `error: [Errno 113] No route to host` and `timeout: timed out` what I'm missing here HOST ?

Comment: "No route to host" means that you try to connect to a sub-net outside your own, and that there is no existing route from your sub-net to that sub-net. "Timed out" is the typical error when no one answers your connect request (think of it as no one answering your phone call).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you help me to change for loop with list of ip's from text file